# Cmd: how to let bat file redirect output to something like /dev/null?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

Under unix, I could simple ABC >/dev/null to avoid any output to screen.
But under windows' cmd, using ABC > NULL will create a file named "NULL". But how to archive the /dev/null like unix?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty close. Try NUL instead of NULL.

```
ABC > NUL
```

Answer (score 2):

Every folder has a nul device.  It is one of the reserved names. These can be used in commands to refer to devices. Eg:

```
copy filename con
```

copies a file to the console window.

Here are the reserved names defined by CMD:

```
CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, 
COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, 
LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9
CONIN$, CONOUT$, CONERR$
```

Comment: and also `conin$` and `conout$`